# Codeigniter 4 Route Resource For Put Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Why I need to put **/1** in front of the url for put (update) in codeigniter 4 version 4.2.6 ?

routes.php :

```
$routes->resource('ApiManageProfile', ['controller' =>'App\Controllers\ApiData\ApiManageProfile']); // get, put, create, delete
```

ApiManageProfile.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\ApiData;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use Codeigniter\API\ResponseTrait;


class ApiManageProfile extends ResourceController
{   

    use ResponseTrait;
    function __construct()
    {           
        
    }
    

    // equal to get
    public function index()
    {                   
                                           
    }


    // equal to post
    public function create() {        
                        
             
    }

    // equal to get
    public function show($id = null) {
        
    }


    // equal to put             
    public function update($id = null) {              
        $id = $this->request->getVar('id');
        $birthday = $this->request->getVar('birthday');
        $phonenumber = $this->request->getVar('phonenumber');
        echo "TESTING";                                                                                                      
    }
    

    // equal to delete
    public function delete($id = null) {        
        
    }

}
```

Then I use postman to call put **with **/1**** :

```
https://testing.id/index.php/ApiManageProfile/1?id=71&phonenumber=1122211&birthday=2023-01-20
```

**The code run correctly.**

But if I use postman to call put **without /1** :

https://testing.id/index.php/ApiManageProfile?id=71&phonenumber=1122211&birthday=2023-01-20

Then I got this error :

```
 "title": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
    "type": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Can't find a route for 'put: ApiManageProfile'.",
```

**For the previous version codeigniter 4 Version 4.1.2 it is working without a problem**

I cannot change all my Rest API to use /1 in front of the url for put because my Application is already launch. If I change the code in react native it will need a time to update the application. And people cannot update the data.

Codeigniter 4 seem change something in newest update version 4.2.6. Causing my routes broken in the application.

Seriously need help for this. What I can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$routes->resource('ApiManageProfile', ['controller' =>'\App\Controllers\ApiData\ApiManageProfile']); // get, put, create, delete
```

generates RESTFUL routes including the following for the `PUT` action.

```php
$routes->put('ApiManageProfile/(:segment)', '\App\Controllers\ApiData\ApiManageProfile::update/$1');
```

The segment isn't optional.

If you would like to implement the segment to be optional, exclude it from the generated routes and declare it explicitly that way.

```php
$routes->resource(
    'ApiManageProfile', 
    ['controller' =>'\App\Controllers\ApiData\ApiManageProfile', 'except' => 'update']
); // get, create, delete

$routes->put(
    'ApiManageProfile',
    '\App\Controllers\ApiData\ApiManageProfile::update'
);
```

Comment: The trick seem did it. But unfortunetly I call the routes like this : /ApiManageProfile/  there is a backslash in the end of the routes in my application. Then now how is it  ?

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't seem a problem with blackslah or not.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help.

Comment: I am glad you solved the problem. Save my times alot.